# Subtle point in Class Theory: is the intersection of two classes a set of a class?

Tags: set-theory

Context: self-study from Smullyan & Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (revised ed., 2010).

Suppose that all classes are subclasses of a "basic universe" $V$, that is:

- every set is a class, i.e. every element of $V$ is a subclass of $V$
- every subclass of a set is a set, i.e. every subclass of any element of $V$ is an element of $V$
- the empty class $\varnothing$ is a set
- For any sets $a$ and $b$, $\{a, b\}$ is a set
- If $x$ is a set, then $\bigcup x$ is a set, where $\bigcup x = \{z: \exists y: (z \in y \land y \in x)\}$
- If $x$ is a set, the its power set is also a set.

Now, it is shown that if $A$ is a non-empty **class**, then $\bigcap A$ is a **set**.

It follows that if $x$ and $y$ are sets, then $\bigcap \{x, y\}$ is a set.

BUT ...  is it also the case that $A \cap B$ is also a set?

$A \cap B$ is the class of all sets such that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.

It seems to me that might not necessarily be the case that $A \cap B$ is a set.

What do we have?

If $A$ and $B$ are classes, then $A \cap B$ cannot be the same thing as $\bigcap C$ for some class $C$, is this correct? Because neither $A$ and $B$ can be elements of classes?

This point is not made clear in any texts on the subject I've seen (which I admit is not many).

(Also, there appears not to be a category for class theory.)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Huh? $\mathsf{Ord}\subseteq V$, but $\mathsf{Ord}$ is not a set. Should "of another class" be "of another *set*"? Regardless, that doesn't seem relevant to the question (of course $A\cap B$ need not be a set if $A,B$ are allowed to be proper classes - take e.g. $A=B=V$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, it seems obvious now. Thank you for this. The point is not usually explained in the literature, and perhaps it could do with being so.